# Override the LANG variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, lang

I'm running a script that contains the LANG variable set to 'french',
when i run it manually with

```
$(pwd)/script_name
```

It works fine, for example, i see the "e'"
translated properly, but when is run by a cronjob, It seems like the LANG variable is set to english_us, i see the 'e`' as '?'

I have no idea why this happens,even when running from a cronjob, the script should set its LANG to french, as it does when i run it manually.
Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure it's not inheriting it from your .profile?

Comment: nope, there's no declaration of LANG in .bash_profile

Comment: Do you set any other locale-related environment variables in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`?

Comment: no, just double checked, no locale-related vars are set

Comment: Is it possible to set `LANG=french` within `$(pwd)/script_name` ?

Comment: the problem is that i need to set that in the cron, as far as i know ids not possible, i think that this behavior comes from the fact that the cron is installed on another machine...

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables right on the command line within your crontab, like so:

```
* * * * * LANG=french script_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the environment variable of the process running the script using "export"
so it needed to be : export LANG=french, got this from https://superuser.com/a/153378/257000